# What is a proper Pub/Sub for the nearest documents sorted by custom fields?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

In my Meteor project, I have documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "cgR25FAxb3tbYShjN",
    "owner" : "6mQKnNnwkQYSaaAMr",
    "username" : "admin",
    "filename" : "5sQqwbDFBcZZ.png",
    "title" : "Title",
    "points" : 2,
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -119.981134343, 
            20.635934343
        ]
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-15T10:27:20.956Z")
}
```

I am able to find the nearest documents by this query:

```
Photos.find({loc: {$near: { $geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [lng, lat]}}}});
```

What I want to be able to do is sort all nearby documents by something like `points` or `createdAt`. I am able to do this if I publish all documents at once.

**The Problem:**

Publishing 200+ documents at once isn't ideal in the least bit. I want to be able to limit the amount being returned to the client and request more as I need it. The problem is: if I do that with a simple `{limit: 20}` in the query, there will probably be a document that is a little farther away that has more points. This will basically screw up the all sorting.

I considered finding all documents on the server at once, then sorting and returning 20 at a time and so on, but won't this put a huge load on my server? Storing 200+ documents in memory per user doesn't seem like a good idea either.

**Update:**

The more I think about this the more I realize that it's a requirement to do a large query on the server first, then pass the data to the client manually. Even if I did a `$geoWithin` look up, if I'm limiting the pub to 20 documents, they will still be out of order when I sort them because they are fetched at different times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `$minDistance` or `$maxDistance` too along with the query.

```
Photos.find({loc: {$near: { $geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [lng, lat]}},$maxDistance: 0.01}});
```

The `0.01` in the query is in radians.

Refer [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/).

Comment: Is that a requirement? It works just fine without it. Obviously it's finding every document in the database, but that's what I want. I don't particularly want to limit it to distance. Even then, that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: what you do is in this case is pass a parameter to the publication with respect to distance as it is changed.

Comment: I guess I don't really see how that's different from limiting the number of documents. If there is a doc with 2 points 0.5 miles away, and a 10 point doc at 30 miles away, they will still be out of order because they are fetched at different times.